# Are you allowed to quit your job?

Tags: halacha, employment

If you have a family to support and don't have another job lined up, are you allowed to quit your job?

Comment: There is no way to answer this question without knowing a host of other factors. Ask a rabbi.

Comment: I agree with @DovF. To make this question answerable, it might be possible to reformulate it to get at an underlying principle rather than at a ruling for a question that's entirely dependent on the particular situation.

Comment: Are you allowed to make bad decisions or take risks?